# How to stream live video stream using Python

Tags: python, youtube

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to extract the information out of the live YouTube video (video to text) but I cannot find any solution to fetch live YouTube streaming video using Python.

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: I'd check out streamlink, a popular tool to get several streaming platforms including Youtube and have them play in a local video player. The Tool is writting in Python itself, so it might help: https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python is an option as an api with youtube interaction, but it only works through youtube. Other than that, you could use pytube to download the file and open the file using os.